# Create a shortcut of a certain Settings Package

Tags: wi-fi, settings, lock-screens

Is there a way to create a shortcut of certain package of Android Settings. The main target is create a shortcut of "Screen Lock" and "WiFi" Functions while the settings app is locked except those?

Device used is a Chinese Tablet running on KitKat 4.4.2 O/S

New Edit:

The Tablet is using a Kiosk Mode (Kid's Place) it doesn't support wallpapers or widgets to be notified.

Comment: You can try [Quick shortcut maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) - don't know on kiosk-mode

Answer (score 0):

Since what lock app you're using is unknown, I'll just list some apps that create activity shortcuts in various ways so you could verify if any of those work with your lock.

- [Nova Launcher](http://novalauncher.com/) - a launcher that could add activity shortcuts to the homescreen.
- [More Shortcuts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.moreshortcuts) - also adds to the homescreen, but a standalone app and can be used with any launcher.
- [Bar Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coinsoft.android.barshortcuts) - creates a shortcut in the notification dropdown, one of the options is "all settings", under which most if not all settings subitems are listed.

Comment: Sorry I've just added the Kiosk Mode used for the Tablet that doesn't support widgets. Does Nova Launcher works as Kiosk Mode? Besides it's Launcher does it include options for Quick Settings?

Comment: I don't know about either since I never used Kiosk Mode, sorry... You should just try and see for yourself.